# Create new field for count of other field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following strucutre in my DB, for which I need to count the `Tripduration`'s and introduce a new field below each respective `"EndStation"`, which gives the `"Tripcount"` based on the number of `Tripdurations`.

```
"_id": 1,
"Tripcount": 4,
"Trips_out": [
    {
        "EndStation": 3119,
        "Tripcount": // This should be 3
        "Tripduration": [
            544,
            364,
            34
        ]
    },
    {
        "EndStation": 3081,
        "Tripcount": // This should be 1
        "Tripduration": [
            835
        ]
    }
```

I started with the following query, but this one calculates it for ALL tripdurations, it delivers the `Tripcount : 4` at the top:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(    
    [
       {
          "$addFields":{
             "Tripcount":{
                "$reduce":{
                   "input":{
                      "$map":{
                         "input":"$Trips_out",
                         "in":{
                            "$size":"$$this.Tripduration"
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "initialValue":0,
                   "in":{
                      "$add":[
                         "$$value",
                         "$$this"
                      ]
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    ]
)
```

How can this be modified such that it counts the Tripdurations for each EndStation, and inserts it as a new field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** instead of **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce)** as follows:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {            
            "Trips_out" : {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$Trips_out",
                    "as": "trip",
                    "in": {
                        "EndStation" : "$$trip.EndStation",
                        "Tripcount": { "$size": "$$trip.Tripduration" },
                        "Tripduration": "$$trip.Tripduration"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```